# What do these straight lines in the graph mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

Does it mean thermal equilibrium? If the answer is yes, then how do we get to the molecular dissociation stage when we have already reached thermal equilibrium in vibrational mode?
Because equilibrium in the vibrational mode means no more vibration and therefore we do not reach the stage of molecular dissociation.

please explain[image]

Comment: Temperature is normally only _defined_ in equilibrium states, so the fact that you have a temperature axis in your diagram implies that the system it describes (probably a multiatomic gas) is always in the equilibrium. This is not only true for the plateaus of the heat capacity.

Answer (score 4):

If you carefully examine the graph you will see that the ordinate is the specific heat at constant volume as a function of temperature. In certain temperature ranges, the specific heat value is constant. As the temperature increases, new modes of energetic motion become possible.

It has nothing to do with thermal equilibrium because that would involve time behavior of temperature, i.e., $$\frac{\mathrm d T}{\mathrm{dt}}=0.$$ There is no explicit time behavior in this graph.

Of course, if there is a temperature gradient across the substance referred to by the graph, there will be a specific heat gradient, too.